# Get only text from multiple pages with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup, information-retrieval, dom

I have a set of 1000 pages(links) that I get by putting a query to Google. I am using JSoup.  I want to get rid of images, links, menus, videos, etc. and take only the main article from every page.

My problem is that every page has a different DOM tree so I cannot use the same command for every page!  Do you know any way to do this for 1000 pages simultaneously?  I guess that I have to use regular expressions. Something like that perhaps

```
textdoc.body().select("[id*=main]").text();//get id that contains the word main
textdoc.body().select("[class*=main]").text();//get class that contains the word main
textdoc.body().select("[id*=content]").text();//get id that contains the word content
```

But I feel that always I will miss something with this.  Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Element main = doc.select("div.main").first();
Elements links = main.select("a[href]");
```

All different pages have main class for the main article?

Comment: what do you have similar to every page?

Comment: i cannot check 1000 pages :p :p

Comment: just check some... you have to find similar things and make an evolutive algoritm to find the same thing in every page :) is not difficult

Comment: well i have checked already some..That's why i end up in the code that i posted above...But it is not right!!For example some pages have id like mainsomething or somethingmain and others that don't have anything like that...Some pages have the word content in id and classes..so i can never end up with a perfect result..

Comment: so you could use your code editing it: Element main = textdoc.body().select("id*=main")!=null?textdoc.body().select("id*=main"):textdoc.body().select("class*=main")!=null?textdoc.body().select("class*=main"):textdoc.body().select("id*=content"). in this way you search correct main in current page.